# protractor elementExplorer or elementor is not working in node 8

Tags: node.js, protractor

I have upgraded from node 7 to node 8.1.2 and my element explorer stopped working with below error.

normally i uses elementor or find selector in my application and elementor internally uses elementExploror

```
[04.11.11] I/protractor - Starting WebDriver debugger in a child process. Element Explorer is still beta, please report issues at github.com/angular/protractor
[04.11.11] I/protractor -
[04.11.11] I/protractor - Type <tab> to see a list of locator strategies.
[04.11.11] I/protractor - Use the `list` helper function to find elements by strategy:
[04.11.11] I/protractor -   e.g., list(by.binding('')) gets all bindings.
```

Anybody fixed this issue or have any work around for now. I think there is a bug already posted [link to git issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4307)

Comment: The only workaround I have for you is to downgrade back to Node 7 (with NVM). Node 8 isn't supported yet by Protractor.

Comment: Yap, other team is moving forward with node 8 so it is difficult to sustain with version 7 for long time. but for now it saved me for couple of months

Answer (score 0):

You can switch back to the node version(7) that was functional with elementor using n or nvm. Once you are back to your old version, Run elementor which will open the browser. Once the browser is open, switch back to the node version in which your app is built which in your case is 8.1.2.

Hope it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps , it worked for me:

1. Downgrade to node version-v6.11.2
2. Downgrade to Protractor-4.0.9 (npm install -g protractor4.0.9)
3. Do webdriver-manager update
4. Install Elementor ($ npm install elementor -g)
5. Do Webdriver-manager start
6. run elementor